# JDialog and JPanel do not open to their set sizes and do not show their labels?

Tags: java, netbeans

In my Netbeans code I have JPanels and JDialog which are driving me crazy at times.  Some of the controllers on these containers decide not to show up or automatically change size even though I have set up both their size and contents within the code and through using the IDE properties.  For instance some of my jButtons on a certain JPanel does not show its text label or the sizes of some of my text field change.

Any solution to this would be grately appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDialog does not open to it's set size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783714/jdialog-does-not-open-to-its-set-size)

Answer (score 1):

When you create GUI using the NetBeans IDE wizards the Layout manager attached with JPanel and JFrame is GroupLayout and it works as expected.  It keep the size of your JPanel and JFrame as you have specified.

Now if you change the LayoutManager of the JPanel or JFrame then you are on your own.  You must know the consequences of changing the LayoutManager and update / add the required code to make the code to run as expected.

I will suggest you to keep the default LayoutManager as GroupLayout if you want to get what you see in the NetBeans component designer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not provide any code snippet that can show your problem. But let me assume that you are confused with layout behavior. Typically we use Layout manager and delegate to it the responsibility of placing and re-sizing the graphical elements. Layout manager does it work when the parent element is being painted, i.e. during execution of method  `paint()` that happens asynchronously and may be caused by various events (e.g. changing focus, re-sizing of window etc).

In this case all your attempts to change size of specific element by calling its `setSize()` could be overridden by layout manager that decides to change size of the same element differently.

So, if my assumption is correct learn to use layout managers and ask more specific questions if you have any difficulties with them.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment.  I'm using Netbeans and my question is that when an IDE is not able to take care of these GUI compartment and would cause the developer more pain than anything, then why is the point of using one.  It'd be more time effective to do this from base up.  I'm new to java and of course need to learn a lot and the reason I employed Netbeans was to save time and gradually build up on my knowledge but it seems that Netbeans is just an extra thing to learn.

Comment: But I do appreciate you for your kind help in making me understand the concept behind layout manager!